# AS2 - Multiple dynamic test boxes with one scrollpane/bar

Tags: actionscript-2

For high scores in my game I have set out a static text box for the rank and multiple dynamic single line text boxes for username and score. Since I will be showing the top 50 scores I need the scroll function.
I know how to do this for a single text box but am stumped how to get this to work for multiple. Have searched and searched.

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You could either:

1. Put all of your text boxes in a new MovieClip, mark that clip as "Export for ActionScript", give it an identifier, and then enter that identifier into the contentPath of a ScrollPane component. The ScrollPane will then move all of the text boxes as a unit.
2. Use the DataGrid component instead of text boxes. That will let you have rows for each user, and columns for the rank, username, and score.